# Which dialects pronounce "pen" as "pin"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

I recently encounter someone who said *pen* exactly as I would say *pin*. I looked in my dictionary only to find these pronunciations:

> pen — `|pen|`
>
> pin — `|pin|`

No crossover was listed or alternative options presented.

I have heard of people doing this before but I was surprised at how exact it was. It wasn't said *similar* to "pin"; it was said *exactly* like "pin".

Is there a specific region or dialect where this is common? Are there other instances of `e` being replaced by `i` or is it just this one word?

Comment: In New Zealand, they pronounce 'e's like 'i', and 'i's like 'uh', so that 'fish' sounds like 'fuhsh'.

Comment: I've posted this before, but such questions already remind of me _['the nathe caste of paste'](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPXMHZ4XEs0)_.

Comment: [Band Meeting. Murray. Prisint.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcjmFL_K7o8)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Southern USA is one area where [the pin-pen merger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Pin-pen_merger) is common. It's not restricted to "pin" and "pen", but a lot of words that include /ɪ/ and /ɛ/ before nasals:

> The pin-pen merger is a conditional merger of /ɪ/ and /ɛ/ before the nasal consonants [m], [n], and [ŋ]. The merged vowel is usually closer to [ɪ] than to [ɛ] (examples include: kin-ken, bin-ben, and him-hem). The merger is widespread in Southern American English, and is also found in many speakers in the Midland region immediately north of the South, as well as in less densely populated inland areas of the Western United States, particularly in Bakersfield, California. It is also a characteristic of African American Vernacular English.

[Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2489) has also discussed this, and [examples where the vowels are pronounced the same and differently](http://ils.unc.edu/afporch/audio/dialect/41.html) in a dialect with the merger may also shed some light on the phenomenon.

Comment: I had a friend who changed his name because he couldn't stand the sound of Southern women saying "Ben" (like "Bin" but with a vowel long enough for two syllables).

Answer (score 4):

New Zealand English does this. Australians call it *Kiwese*.

There is a handy phrase book for Australians, which includes such 'jims' as

**McKennock** - person who fixes cars

**pigs** - small devices for pinning washing on clotheslines.

**swab the dicks** - a task for recalcitrant sailors.

[Sorry @Ham, I have the book (ISBN 1 86330 342 1) in front of me, and it says *McKennock*]

Comment: Attach the socks with a couple of pigs.

Comment: From a New Zealander's perspective we DO NOT pronounce "pen" as "pin". Everyone else just pronounces "pin" as "pen" :-)

Comment: The American South has your back (er... bic?)

Answer (score 2):

Some South Africans (I think those influenced by Afrikaaner accents, but by no means only Afrikaaners), seem to pronounced almost all vowels as "i", or nearly so to the point that they are indistinguishable to my English ears.

No doubt someone here can provide more detail on what is happening with that pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from New Zealanders - some of whom have accents so heavy they need to be translated - people Adelaide in Australia also have a distinctive accent similar to, but not as heavy, as the Kiwi one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from eastern Kentucky and we make no difference when pronouncing these two words. Pin and pen are spoken with the same sound. I've never understood the issue with this. "En" and "in" both pronounced the same as "n"? If one adds a "p" in front of each they are both pronounced the same. That's why in eastern Kentucky we sometimes say "ink-pen" instead of just "pen" in order to differentiate between the two words.

All of Appalachia and most of the southern USA pronounce the two words with the same sound. It's the rest of the USA that has it wrong.