# Tin percint of all Dimmocrats in the Sinnate

Tags: pronunciation

T**I**n perc**I**nt of all D**I**mmocrats in the S**I**nnate are s**I**nsitive to this concern, but the repres**I**ntative from P**I**nnsylvania th**E**nks that some common s**I**nse should be applied.

Two questions:

Am I mistaken if I think that most Americans do *not* pronounce words in this way?

Am I mistaken in thinking that lately every narrator on every TV commercial and every news broadcaster in the U.S.A. has been doing this?  It seems as if there are no exceptions, and since I expect news broadcasters and the like to be exceptionally superstitious, I wonder if someone with a crystal ball ordered them to do this (via some published pronunciation guide distributed to people in their line of work) and they're fearful of disobeying?

Comment: Is there a sample of this somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you're going to have to provide some evidence to support your claim.

Comment: Yes , please link to some audio clip.  There are certainly some regional dialects which pronounce the E more like an I, but US national newscasters traditionally have not used such a dialect, as far as I can tell. How recently have you noticed this phenomenon?

Comment: Just going from the phonetic pattern of the modifications, this looks like the pin-pen merger (but I disagree that this is commonly heard from commercial narrators or broadcasters): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Pin.E2.80.93pen_merger

Comment: @BrianHitchcock : Today, and every day for the past several months. Every news broadcaster and every narrator on every commercial does it.  Until recent months, this was a minority pronunciation, and now all others are banished from network television.

Comment: Okay, I don't doubt it. But different people hear vowels differently, just as different people pronounce vowels differently, so we'd like to hear some particularly blatant example for ourselves. I haven't had a TV for the past four years, so I have not experienced the shift you cite.

Comment: This might be a good question to take up with the American Dialect Society.  They are quite interested in changes of pronunciation. IMO it's not really a question about English Language & Usage. Also, your digression about superstition and crystal ball is extraneous and should be removed from your question.  And your claim that **all** broadcasters made this shift requires samples from each network and many commercials, both before and after the shift, to be convincing. It's better not to use "all", "always" or "never" in this forum, as they invite disproving by a single counterexample.

Comment: Looks more like a NZ accent.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: it certainly seems like a question about the English language to me. Micheal Hardy: I am also not convinced that all news broadcasters pronounce "pen" and "pin," etc., identically. Nobody else seems to have noticed this; you should give us an example so we can hear it. And how would they all coordinate their pronunciations? I don't think there is any such universal pronunciation guide for people on American TV.

Answer (score 4):

Q1: No; it appears you are probably correct. While I don't know the population numbers, here's a map to give you some idea of the geographical distribution:

[image: map of pin-pen merger in the United States]

http://www.ling.upenn.edu/phono_atlas/maps/Map3.html

Q2: Yes, as far as I can tell. I just looked on Hulu for a random news broadcast, and found "[Good Morning America](http://www.hulu.com/watch/839574)" for Wednesday September 2, 2015.

Here is what I heard:

> “three **men** suspected of killing” @ about 18:00 
>   
> “**chem**icals bought in China” @ 18:30 or so 
>   
> “so much coming up on this **Wedn**esday morning” @ 18:50

They did not sound to me like "min," "kimmicals" or "Winzday." As far as I can tell, all of these had the regular /ɛ/ sound rather than /ɪ/. So there are certainly exceptions, assuming this is even a real trend at all.

Comment: Related: [Which dialects pronounce “pen” as “pin”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33259/which-dialects-pronounce-pen-as-pin)

Answer (score 1):

You are not mistaken about Q 1. A good sampling can be found on Youtube videos about 'fails', how-tos and politics.

About Q 2, I haven't noticed that on NBC or ABC news, but it's possible it has been so gradually introduced that it didn't grab my attention.